# 4sum time limit exceeded (leetcode)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

This is the problem I am having, the question is to find out possible combinations of length 4 from an array nums of length N, whose sum must be equal to the target given.

```
def fourSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    from itertools import combinations
    comb=list(itertools.combinations(nums, 4))
    lst=[]
    for i in list(comb):
        i=sorted(i)
        if i not in lst and sum(i)==target:
          lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

I wrote the above code but its showing that it exceeded the time limit, can anyone help me with this?

```
[-497,-480,-477,-470,-452,-448,-440,-412,-390,-381,-372,-372,-369,-366,-355,-346,-340,-337,-322,-321,-311,-296,-258,-249,-248,-232,-215,-199,-174,-154,-128,-122,-122,-117,-115,-113,-110,-89,-86,-84,-78,-71,-69,-53,-49,-35,-25,-21,-7,3,7,21,25,30,47,52,81,84,87,91,96,157,161,167,178,184,210,217,228,236,274,277,283,286,290,301,302,341,352,354,361,367,384,390,412,421,458,468,483,484,486,487,490,491] 
target: 8377
```

This is the last executed test case.

Comment: Your algorithm -- iterating through all possible combinations and finding the combinations that work -- is inefficient. You need to go through `nC4` combinations for each list, and that can quickly get big (100C4 is 3.9 million). The point of the exercise is to come up with an efficient algorithm. If you're struggling, look for some tutorials that explain how a more efficient algorithm works. Here's one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-four-elements-that-sum-to-a-given-value-set-2/

Comment: Is the expected result an empty list? since the maximum value in the case is 497, so 8377 cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from selecting a very inefficient algorithm, your implementation has a few efficiency issues too:

- there is no need to cast the iterator returned by `combinations` to a list (you're even recasting it a second time in your `for`!): just use it, you will save both space and time
- there is no need to sort the `comb` - it already has its element in the same order of the input list
- there is no need to test if a valid combination is already in the result list: you will see each combination just once (unless you have duplicate values in your input)

Try this, it already is much faster even without changing the algorithm:

```
def new_fourSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    from itertools import combinations
    lst=[]
    for i in itertools.combinations(nums, 4):
        if sum(i)==target:
          lst.append(i)
    return lst
```